# A condition is omited

Tags: blender

I'm starting with blender and python, and in this activity we have to move in a certain way.
The movement is fine but for some reason in  `elif t <= 4.1 and t > 2.9:` is omited so instead of having the object motionless in position 4.0 it goes executes posx = 0.0*t/5.6

```
import bpy

def custom_x_pos(frm):
    """ Return object location for frame 'frm'

    If time < 0, pos.x = 0
    If time = 2.9, pos.x = 40
    If time = 4.1, pos.x = 40
    If time = 5.6, pos.x = 0
    If time = 9.2, pos.x = 70
    If time = 9.9, pos.x = 70
    
    In between, linear interpolation
    """

    # each frame is 1/24 secs. First, we compute time
    t = frm/24.0

    if t <=0 :
        posx = 0.0
    elif t <= 2.9:
        posx = 4.0*t/2.9
    elif t <= 4.1 and t > 2.9:
        posx = 4.0 
    elif t <= 5.6 and t > 4.1:
        posx = 0.0*t/5.6
    elif t <= 9.2 and t > 5.6:
        posx = 7.0*t/9.2
    else: # if t > 9.2 secs
        posx = 7.0

    return posx
#

obj = bpy.context.active_object

# For frame 1, we set location and insert keyframe
frm = 1
obj.location[0] = custom_x_pos(frm)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location',frame=frm)


# For frame 69.6, we set location and insert keyframe
frm = 69.6
obj.location[0] = custom_x_pos(frm)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location',frame=frm)


# For frame 98.4, we set location and insert keyframe
frm = 98.4
obj.location[0] = custom_x_pos(frm)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location',frame=frm)


# For frame 134.4, we set location and insert keyframe
frm = 134.4
obj.location[0] = custom_x_pos(frm)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location',frame=frm)


# For frame 220.8, we set location and insert keyframe
frm = 220.8
obj.location[0] = custom_x_pos(frm)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location',frame=frm)


# For frame 237.6, we set location and insert keyframe
frm = 237.6
obj.location[0] = custom_x_pos(frm)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location',frame=frm)
```

I try the same code before with the sames conditions but i  dont know why this in particular.